# Having Trouble Searching and Putting into Array During a Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop, os.system

So I have an output.txt file I'm looking to loop through looking for this line " probability=  7.5098503e-03 " and whenever it is found, put that probability value into an array.

I think my searching for "probability" in line isn't working as I get this error:

> File "test.py", line 29, in search
>
> if probability in line:
>
> NameError: global name 'probability' is not defined

**I'm also not sure my putting the probabilities into an array every loop will work properly either...**

```
prob=[]

voltages = [0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5]
for voltage in voltages:
    update_code(voltage)
    os.system("hspice pbit.sp >output.txt")
    def search():
        with open('output.txt') as f:
            datafile = f.readlines()
        for line in datafile:
            if probability in line:
                return True
        return False
    if search():
        print('True')
        prob=[] = line
    else:
        print('False')
```

I would love assistance from this awesome intellectual community!

Comment: The line `prob = [] = line` doesn't make any sense. You should use `prob.append()` if you want to add something to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes for that to be a string literal

```
if 'probability' in line:
```

Otherwise that line would expect `probability` is a variable